# Expedia Error - Cached availability could not be found. Please reissue availability

Tags: api, caching

I have used Expedia Hotel API in my project.

Each request gives me a Cache ID for the next page. So I can make request to next page using that Cache ID, and its working fine.

I'm maintaining a session of the Cache ID's, so that I can navigate to previous pages, if user click on Previous Button.

But when I click on previous page button, Its showing error : Cached availability could not be found. Please reissue availability.

This could happen if I used that cache ID after a long time, but I'm calling previous page immediately. It shouldn't expire that fast.

Any Ideas? Is there any way to tell server to not expire those ID's so fast...

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the Expedia (EAN) support team can help with something like this. The cache is supposed to last 15 to 30m according to their docs, so if it's expiring immediately, and certain that you're passing the correct cache ID, this is something that can only be addressed by that team.

https://support.ean.com/home